# Delete first letter of the words using visual basic

Tags: vba, vb6, libreoffice

I have a code, which can change last letters of words to the dot. I need to how, *how to change the code, so when I write some words, in output I will get them without first letter*?

for ex:

- Input: `Hello,how are you?`
- Output: `ello, ow re ou?`

Here is my code:

```
Sub New5
dim s, ns as String
dim r as String
s = inputbox("Input text")
r = "Inputed text:" & chr(9) & s & chr(13)
for i = 2 to len(s)
if mid(s,i,1)=" " then ns = ns + "." else ns = ns + mid(s,i-1,1)
next i
ns = ns + "."
r = r & "Result of work:" & chr(9) & ns
MsgBox r
End Sub
```

Comment: You have added both a vb6 tag and a vb.net one to your question. Which are you using? - They're different languages!

Comment: vb 6, will delete now vb.net

Comment: vb6 and vba tags are also conflicting?

Comment: Saying "have a code" is also bizarre.  I suspect you mean "incantation" or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For VB6:

```
Private Sub Convert()
  Dim strIn as string
  Dim strA() As String
  Dim strOut As String
  Dim iX As Integer
  
  strIn - "Hello, how are you?"
  strA = Split(strIn, " ")
  
  For iX = 0 To UBound(strA)
    strA(iX) = Mid$(strA(iX), 2)
  Next
  
  strOut = Join(strA, " ")
End Sub
```

Incidentally your libreoffice tag is also inappropriate as LibreOffice doesn't use the same language as vb6 or vba.

Comment: Understand you, but I need that when I write some text in input window and then in result window it will delete first letter

Comment: I've changed something in code and it works, thank you! I have one more question about VB, and if it possible for you, check pls. I will mark it now as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just saw this was tagged vb6. This is a vb.net answer.

If you want to get rid of the first letter of each word, the first thing to do is get the words. `String.Split` will return an array based on the split character you provide. In this case that character is a space. The small `c` following the string tells the compiler that this is `Char`.

Now we can loop through each word and cut off the first letter. I am storing the shortened words in a `List(Of String)`. You can get rid of the first letter by using `Substring` passing the start index. We want to start at the second letter so we pass `1`. Indexes start at `0` for the first letter.

Finally, use `String.Join` to put everything back together.

`Chr`, `Len`, `Mid`, and `MsgBox` are all left overs from VB6. They work for backward compatibility but it is a good idea to learn the .net classes functionality.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    New5()
End Sub

Private Sub New5()
    Dim input = InputBox("Input text")
    Dim words = input.Split(" "c)
    Dim ShortWords As New List(Of String)
    For Each word In words
        ShortWords.Add(word.Substring(1))
    Next
    Dim shortenedString = String.Join(" ", ShortWords)
    MessageBox.Show(shortenedString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know how do this on vb 6?

Comment: @dextermikles Why don't you move to vb.net. vb6 is a very old technology.

Comment: @Mary I have the impression that a lot of students are using VB6 quite widely still, somewhere, probably mandated by their school or university. (Not to mention that there's plenty of existing VB6 production code that is decades old and still being maintained.)

Comment: @StayOnTarget Good point. Students should be learning the new technology. VS is free for students. The VB6 market is there but shrinking. Let's leave that to the mature programmers and teach the youngsters the new stuff.